# How can I pass large values as parameters in ASP.NET WebApi?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi that allows a list of files to be sent to it. The argument is a simple list of objects that contain a name and a list of bytes. When I post small files to it, it works fine, but when I post a large file the method is called, but the parameter is null.

I assume there's a setting or something in the model binding I can change, but I can't figure out what setting to set. Especially since the method itself does get called, but only that parameter gets set to null.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try setting values for  maxAllowedContentLength or maxRequestLength or maxJsonLength

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's because you reached **maxRequestLength** size.

Did you try this approach?

> http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: It turns out this was the problem. I was under the impression that if this value was nog high enough, it would always result in a 500 Internal Server Error. In WebApi this is not the case it seems. The 'request too large' exception is apparently thrown, but seems to be handled internally and just changed to a null value for the parameter. Setting this value high enough did solve the issue.

Comment: Yes, I exactly have this problem,

Comment: @Esi I'm glad you found this answer then! :)

Comment: hi @Robba, I exactly have this problem , but when I set the Max Length to max the ERROR 500 disappear but on the server side I just get the null Object. I'm using WebApi web service for my server. do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

You could try to enlarge the max content request limit. 
Note that the limit is in bytes. Default IIS 7 limit I think is 30MB.

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="length"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good suggestion. I already set this to be high enough though. If this value is not high enough in the configuration you get a 404 status and the method will not be called at all as opposed to my situation.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't helped you,but my other suggestions is to set  `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="Large Value"/>`, and to check if request headers have multipart content header, and then to try read it with `ReadAsMultipartAsync()`.